# Custom Dictionary in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office-2013-preview

I have MS Word 2013 installed on my system and me along with my friend use it regularly. I know how to add custom dictionaries, but is it possible that each user has his own custom dictionary.

During spell check, If i add a custom word, that should not appear in his custom dictionary, and vice versa.

Eg: In my custom dictionary, the word "Aple" is added. It should still show an error in the other person's documents, but not for me.

Comment: Using separate user accounts when using Word should solve this, as settings like this are stored under each user profile.